# Fill a DataSet using a SqlTableAdapter according to ID #

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, tableadapter

I am currently trying to fill a tableadapter on form load, according to a certain ID number.

The line of code that is already provided fills the table adapter with all the records in the table.

However, I just want the records `where ID = 1`

I am using VB 2012 with SQL Server

Can someone please explain how I go about doing this?

The original line of code is:

```
    Me._6OrdersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Online_Portal_Solutions_DatabaseDataSet._6Orders)
```

When I try to add a new query to the table in the dataset designer I get this warning message: (Not too sure what it means:

> "The new command text returns data with schema different from the schema of the main query. Check your query's command text if this is not desired."

The query I added was as follows:

```
SELECT OrderNoID, CustomerID, CollectionDate, DeliveryDate
        , ServiceType, PostalZone, DeliveryAddress, Product
        , HazardType, Weight, NoOfPallets, OtherNotes
FROM   [6Orders]
WHERE  (HaulierID = 1)
```

I called the query fillhaulierjkp and changed the original line of code as follows:

```
    Me._6OrdersTableAdapter.fillhaulierjkp(Me.Online_Portal_Solutions_DatabaseDataSet._6Orders)
```

Then when I run the app I get this error when the page loads:

> "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."

I just want to fill the table adapter with the select statement but I want the user to be able to browse through the records using the binding navigator

Comment: Post some relevant codes showing what you have tried so far, then we can try to fix necessary parts to get only records where ID = 1.

Comment: @har07 I have provided what I have tried in the question; could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That last problem is due to constraints set on your `DataSet`. Maybe you have columns not accepting null values or unique keys being violated. Either way, you must either remove the faulting constraints, change your server query so that it matches with your schema or turn off constraints by setting [`EnforceConstraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints.aspx) to `False`. Normally when this error is thrown you would also have faulting rows having their [`RowError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowerror.aspx) property indicating what constraint(s) is causing the problem.

As for your former problem, it's caused by your server resultset being different from what the `DataTable` schema expects. If, for example, you have a `String` column whose name matches an `int` server column, this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

refering to your error, be sure you are using the Query Editor so you can get a visual on the columns selected.

For parameter to load your form

replace

```
where ID = 1
```

with

```
where ID = ?
```

This will create a @parameter1 statement in your table adapter.

Then fill with parameter e.g. nPID

```
Me.TA1.Fill(Me.DsClients.tblClients_Dems, nPID)
```